# sql issue to query product name

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

I am new to `SQL` , I have been looking for on line resources but have not find anything yet to solve my problem. Basically i have three tables below:

```
 ORDERTBL(ORDERID,ORDERDATE,ORDERSTATUS),
 PRODUCT(PRODUCTID,PRODUCT_NAME),
 ORDERLINKPRODUCTS(ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY,ORDERLINKPRODUCTID)
```

I want to get all the `product name` from the products tables for a specific order which i should query from `ORDERLINKPRODUCTS` since it contains all the orders.

for instance please find test data available in 3 tables:

Table ORDERTBL:

```
ORDERID=1,ORDERDATE= 24May, ORDERSTATUS=Process
```

Table PRODUCTS:

```
    PRODUCID =1  PRODUCT_NAME = spoon    PRODUCID =2  PRODUCT_NAME = soap
```

Table :ORDERLINKPRODUCTS:

```
ORDERID=1 PRODUCTID = 1 QUANTITY=3  ORDERLINKPRODUCTID=1    ORDERID=1 PRODUCTID = 2 QUANTITY=1  ORDERLINKPRODUCTID=2
```

I am trying to make a select statements that display all the product name of an order. For instance display all product name of `orderid=1` which will return spoon,soap.

Any suggestion how to do it please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `JOIN` keyword in `SQL` to join the three tables to be able to access `PRODUCTNAME` and show that table data. More about [Join clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT prod.PRODUCT_NAME 
            FROM ORDERTBL ord 
            INNER JOIN ORDERLINKPRODUCTS link ON ord.ORDERID = link.ORDERID
            INNER JOIN PRODUCT prod ON link.PRODUCTID = prod.PRODUCTID  
            WHERE ord.ORDERID = 1
```

[SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5451a/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can find orders with products ilsted using this

```
SELECT O.ORDERID, RTRIM(
            XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, P.PRODUCT_NAME ||',') ORDER BY O.ORDERID).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') as Products
FROM ORDERTBL O 
  INNER JOIN ORDERLINKPRODUCTS L
    ON O.ORDERID = L.ORDERID
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT P
    ON L.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID  
GROUP BY O.ORDERID
```

and products listed with its quantity using this:

```
SELECT O.ORDERID, RTRIM(
            XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, P.PRODUCT_NAME || '(' || L.QUANTITY || '),') ORDER BY O.ORDERID).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') as Products
FROM ORDERTBL O 
  INNER JOIN ORDERLINKPRODUCTS L
    ON O.ORDERID = L.ORDERID
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT P
    ON L.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID  
GROUP BY O.ORDERID
```

You can add `WHERE clause` clause to filted orders as you whish.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5451a/11)**